Get exception from airflow taskinstance
I have a function inside my airflow DAG that executes as the last task and checks for any failed task starting with strategy_, then after storing all of them writes the relevant information to a file to keep logs of what happened
This is what i have
def final_status(**kwargs) -> None:
    """ """

    failed_tasks = []

    for task_instance in kwargs['dag_run'].get_task_instances():

        if (task_instance.current_state() != State.SUCCESS 
            and task_instance.task_id != kwargs['task_instance'].task_id
            and task_instance.task_id.startswith("strategy_")
           ):
            
            failed_tasks.append(task_instance)

    write_to_file(kwargs['dag'].dag_id, kwargs['dag_run'].execution_date, failed_tasks)

    if failed_tasks:
        raise Exception(f"Task(s) {failed_tasks} failed. Failing this DAG run")


def write_to_file(dag_name: str, dag_run_time: str, failed_tasks: list) -> None:
    """ """
    file_name = f"{dag_name}_{dag_run_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")}.txt"

    for task in failed_tasks:
        print("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")
        print(f"Failed task id: {task.task_id}")
        print(f"Failed task execution time: {task.execution_date}")
        print(f"Failed task status: {task.state}")
        print(f"Failed task error: {task.error()}")
        print("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")

    print(f"Writting to {file_name}")


This code works, but the exception that made the task fail cannot be retrieved, I have treid task.error and task.error(), task.error returns an object so i know the method exists, but maybe it doesn't work as I expect.
The task that will fail is this one
def print_file_name_2():
    print("a" + 5)

I want to capture TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
Any ideas on how to capture the task exception?
